# Changing style of only selected polygons in L.geoJSON layer?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, d3, react

So, I'm going to show a lot of polygons in my Leaflet map but I need an id for each polygon, the URL comes in a path like this.

In fact I wouldn't even need an id, if I could somehow get some properties like that, like stroke = red would work for me, because I want to change a property when the path is in red.

```
<path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="red" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="red" fill-opacity="0" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M477 171L469 171L468 176L455 175L455 171L459 171L461 167L465 167L467 163L471 163L472 160L479 153L488 148L493 147L494 158L489 159L487 163L477 167L477 171z"></path>
```

My code for all polygons

```
 L.geoJSON(polygon, {
        style: function (feature) {
          return {
            stroke: true,
            fillColor: feature.color,
            fillOpacity: feature.opacity,
            color: feature.color,
            opacity: feature.opacity,
            weight: 2,
          };
        },
      })
        .bindPopup(function (layer) {
          return layer.feature.properties.name;
        })
        .addTo(map);
```

and the function that will change, but in this way is not working

```
      case 3:
        const elm3 = d3.selectAll(`g path[style = "fill: red"]`);
        elm3.style('opacity', checked ? 0 : 0.7);

        break;
```

Comment: You might need to do a little manual editing of the data in QGIS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be simpler to let Leaflet do the desired change in style through the `style` option.

Set initial opacity for features which have the desired color with the `style` function to some predefined value:

```
redOpacity = 0;

function myStyle(feature) {
  var opacity = (feature.color == 'red') ? redOpacity : feature.opacity;
  return {
    stroke: true,
    fillColor: feature.color,
    fillOpacity: opacity,
    color: feature.color,
    opacity: opacity,
    weight: 2,
  };
}

myGeoJSON = L.geoJSON(polygon, {
  style: myStyle,
})
.bindPopup(function (layer) {
  return layer.feature.properties.name;
})
.addTo(map);
```

Then when needed simply change this value and set style function again with `setStyle` method to refresh layer style:

```
redOpacity = 0.7;
myGeoJSON.setStyle(myStyle);
```

Comment: hummm, this way is much better in fact, I have one more question: I am making the css change outside of useEffect, I have a handleChangeFilter function that is activated when my checkbox is checked, how could I do this set style within that function?

Comment: I suppose this `useEffect` is related to `React`, and since I'm not familiar with it, I can't help you here. If the above answer helped you in some way, it's customary to mark it as accepted to let other users know that it was useful.

Comment: Ok. But there is a way that i can put an id for each polygon?

Comment: Please ask a separate question with more details about how should this id look like and the logic of assigning/creating this id.

Comment: ready https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380715/how-can-i-put-different-id-in-different-paths-on-my-leaflet-map