# Putting different id in different paths on my Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, javascript, mapping, d3, react

I have many polygons to display on map like this:

```js
      L.geoJSON(polygon, {
        style: function (feature) {
          return {
            stroke: true,
            fillColor: feature.color,
            fillOpacity: opacity,
            color: feature.color,
            opacity: opacity,
            weight: 2,
          };
        },
      })
        .bindPopup(function (layer) {
          return layer.feature.properties.name;
        })
        .addTo(map);
```

and each polygon generate a `<path>` like this

```js
<path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="red" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="red" fill-opacity="0" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M477 171L469 171L468 176L455 175L455 171L459 171L461 167L465 167L467 163L471 163L472 160L479 153L488 148L493 147L494 158L489 159L487 163L477 167L477 171z"></path>
```

Is there a way that I can put a different id for each path?

Comment: You could assign id when layer features/polygons are created. What would be the logic of assigning this id to polygons?

Comment: i need the tag ID on the <path> tag, because i want to select this path in d3.select but just the path with the id that i put

Comment: Sounds to me like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). *Why* do you want to have IDs on the DOM SVG paths?

Comment: ...and why do you want to select the paths via `d3.select()`? Event handling? Manually modifying the path? Keep in mind that Leaflet will destroy and re-create SVG paths each time the map is panned or zoomed, so you might end up with undesired behaviour.

Comment: because when i click in a checkbox the style in my path with (for exemplo) id = red will change to opacity 0 to 1. When i call my function make this behavior 

  const elm = d3.selectAll(`#red`);
        elm.style('opacity', checked ? 0 : 1);

Comment: My question was not about **why?** but about **how?**. How would you determine what id goes to certain path/feature? Depending on some feature property? What is the rule/formula of this dependance?

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to add id to each path elements, you can be able to achieve that by simply using a jquery script.

**## OPTION 1 : use jQuery once polygons are loaded**

This will do the job. Be Sure to match the right id container, here `map` :

```js
$(function() {
    var id = 0;
    $( "#map path" ).each(function( index ) {
      $( this ).prop('id', id);
      console.log('setting id to "path" element : ' + id);
      id++;
    });
});
```

**## OPTION 2 : onEachFeature Leaflet built-in feature**

If giving an id dynamically to your polygon is an option to target thme later, you should consider using the Leaflet buil-tin feature `onEachFeature` :

```js
var idcnt= 0;
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    feature.properties.id = idcnt;
    console.log(feature);
    console.log('the current id : ' + feature.properties.id);
    idcnt++;
}

L.geoJSON(states, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

The following page implement both methods : http://intermezzo-coop.eu/mapping/L-set-id.html

Use *F12* (web developement tools and / or inspect code to see results). Also, have a look on source code.

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet offers no way of assigning HTML `id` attribute to HTML `path` elements that represent vector layer feature. But since you just want a way to select desired `path` elements from the DOM structure, there is a bit hacked way to do that.

One of the Leaflet style options is `className`, which can be any string. This class name is then added to the `path` element class list. There is no harm if such CSS class actually does not exist, it will be just "misused" to get collection of desired `path` elements with the `document.getElementsByClassName` method.

If in your case you would want to get all elements where `feature.color` has value `'red'`, your code could look something like this:

```
L.geoJSON(polygon, {
  style: function (feature) {
    return {
      stroke: true,
      fillColor: feature.color,
      fillOpacity: opacity,
      color: feature.color,
      opacity: opacity,
      weight: 2,
      className: (feature.color == 'red') ? 'id_red' : '';
    };
  },
})
.bindPopup(function (layer) {
  return layer.feature.properties.name;
})
.addTo(map);

.
.
.

var red_elements = document.getElementsByClassName('id_red');
```